# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.creatReactionCollector is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i have a code that collects a reaction and send an embed when reaction is pressed
the code is :

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "help1")) {
    message.channel.send("Help Is Coming ! ").then(async msg => {
      const emojis = [
        "", //0
        "⚒️", //1
        "❌",
      ];
      for (let i = 0; i < emojis.length; i++) {
        await msg.react(emojis[i]);
      };
      const filter = (reaction, user) => emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id == message.author.id;
      const collector = msg.creatReactionCollector(filter, {
        time: 30000
      });
      collector.on("collect", ({
        emoji,
        users
      }) => {
        const index = emojis.indexOf(emoji.name);
        if (index === 0) {
          let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL({
              format: 'png',
              dynamic: true,
              size: 1024
            }), )
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL({
              format: 'png',
              dynamic: true,
              size: 1024
            }))
            .setTitle('Help')
            .setColor('7289da')
            .addField('check your DMs!', 'The Command Will Be Sent To Your DMs !')
            .setFooter('By Mr Romex')
          msg.channel.send(embed2)
        }

      })
    });
  };
});
```

the error is :

```
(node:2246) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.creatReactionCollector is not a function
    at /home/runner/giveaway-bot/index.js:123:29
```

Comment: You forgot the 'e' in `createReactionCollector`

Comment: `TypeError: msg.creatReactionCollector is not a function` tells you that something is wrong with `msg.creatReactionCollector` specifically that `creatReactionCollector` is not a function. Whenever you get such an error you should first check if there is a typo.

Comment: Independent from the error `TypeError`: Whenever you have a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`  you should in addition check your code because this shows that you have a broken promise chain. The promise chain created by `message.channel.send` does not handle error cases. (Missing `.catch` at the end of the chain).